# Import sass/css file to all Angular components

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular6, angular8

In my file `var.sass` I define the variable `$black`. I would like to use that variable in **ALL** of my `components.sass` files. To do so, do i need to write `@import` in every file or is there any better solution to do that?

We all know that I cannot use those variables inside `components.sass` when I import this kind of files to a global `styles.sass` file.

Comment: Good job this might be a really good question.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you will need to get your var.sass file into your component file(s). Personally, each of my modules requires its own styles.scss file, in each styles.scss I use the SASS @import to grab my global vars file. I have a boilerplate structure that I use for modules that already has the this css wire-up. But maybe there's a even fancier build-time way to include your global SASS ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, this is not possible. The workaround is something you've already done - I'm using a `variables.scss` file that I import to all components that need these variables (shout out to [NetBasal for a short article describing this](https://netbasal.com/angular-cli-and-global-sass-variables-a1b92d8ca9b7)).